# IE iframe and unicode text

Tags: javascript, unicode, iframe, internet-explorer-8, src

I have troubles with iframe in IE. I'm trying to create iframe dynamically and to assign its src attribute to appropriate file according to user selection. I've created a simple html page with inline javascript that reproduces the problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function createIFrame(){
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.id = "myframe";  
      }

      function loadFile(fileName){
        var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
        frame.src = fileName;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="create iframe" onclick="createIFrame()" />
    <input type="button" value="load ansi" onclick="loadFile('ansi.txt')" />
    <input type="button" value="load unicode" onclick="loadFile('unic.txt')" />
    <hr/>
    <iframe id="workingFrame" src="unic.txt"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

ansi.txt - text file saved in ANSI encoding, unic.txt is unicode text file.

Pressing create button iframe is added to DOM. If 'load ansi' button is pressed file content is loaded into iframe without any issues, but 'load unicode' button causes a problem - iframe stays empty.

But if src attribute is defined initially like in case of 'workingFrame' - unicode file is loaded correctly. This issue happens in IE 8, IE 9 suggests to download file instead of rendering it. I need file content to be rendered inside the iframe.

Comment: I tried your example in ie 8 and 9 and it worked perfectly. Have you tried you sample html page yourself, or just your actual code? PS - sorry for posting this as an answer, I don't have comment privledges yet

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I've tried it myself under IIS 7 running on Windows 7 on several PCs. And issue was reproducible. I've created text files with Windows notepad changing its encoding save option.

Comment: OK, I got it to reproduce the error in ie9 & 8, I missed the part about encoding the file with notepad.

Comment: For me though, in ie9 it wouldn't load it even in the initially defined iframe. I did get it to work in both ie9 & 8 by changing the file extension to .html. I'm guessing that's probably not a viable option for you though.

Comment: @EricLaw is right; added `AddType 'text/html;' txt` to your `.htaccess` file and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes this is the way to make unicode text displayed inside the iframe, but it is not applicable to me. I described the reasons in comment .below

Answer (score 0):

What MIME type is your server sending on this response? What CHARSET does the Content-Type HTTP header specify?

If you send text/html instead of text/plain, I bet this works without error.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Changing content-type header to 'text/html' solved one problem but produce another - text formatting is lost.

Comment: Unfortunately this way of problem solution is not applicable to me because I don't have access to production server and problem should be resolved on client part. About the problem - I've noticed that IE loads file content to iframe, it is accessible via iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML but it is not displayed. And iframe.readyState property does not go to "complete", it always "interactive" for unicode files.